# Wacom Penabled Ubuntu as "Graphic tablet" for Mac

Tags: multiple-monitors, mac, touchscreen, wacom

I recently installed last Ubuntu Studio (20lts) on a Fujitsu T730 and i figured how good would be to use this Penabled screen as some type of second screen from a MacBook for example, use the Pen on applications like Unity3D or Bender.

Knows somebody a good software combo on both computers (the other one is a MBP'16) to achieve it?

Thanks in advance, and regards!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Unity3d is not a software but a desktop environment. Bender (i think this is a mistype of blender.) is a good one. I do not know what kind of use you want but I try to guess.

Comment: By the way, I have been a fan of Unity desktop since 12.04 LTS. It is still available on 20.04 LTS `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

**GIMP** - no doubt both hands down, the free picture editor like Photoshop.

`sudo apt install gimp`

[image: gimp]

---

**Inkscape** - new opensource drawing software, like Illustrator. (I've never used this...because I do not have a pen interface but it looks nicer with a pen-tablet like Fujitsu T series.)

`sudo apt install inkscape`

[image: inkscape]